# Suspicious cast to text for a CLIPBOARD_SERVICE: expected ClipboardManager [ServiceCast]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When building a release version of my app the build fails with the following error:

*Error:Error: Suspicious cast to text for a CLIPBOARD_SERVICE: expected ClipboardManager [ServiceCast]*

Debug version builds fine.

If I comment out the pre SDK 11 code below it builds fine.

How can I solve this error?

Code:

```
@TargetApi(11)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void btnCopyClicked(View button) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(aString);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("aString", aString);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

Environment:

- Android Studio 2.3
- Android SDK Tools 25.3.1
- Gradle 3.3
- Android Plugin Version 2.3.0

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
    ...
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in [ServiceCastDetector in lint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/ServiceCastDetector.java). To workaround convert the following code

```
android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(aString);
```

to

```
Object clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
((android.text.ClipboardManager)clipboard).setText(aString);
```